# Is it possible to extraxt information about HOW a user defined function is being called?

Tags: python

Or is it possible to capture the function call itself in any way (describe which values are assigned to the different arguments)?

Sorry for the poor phrasing of the question. Let me explain with some reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import inspect

# 1. Here is Dataframe with some random numbers
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(90,110,size=(rows, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2017, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=rows).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
#print(df)

# 2. And here is a very basic function to do something with the dataframe
def manipulate(df, factor):
    df = df * factor
    return df

# 3. Now I can describe the function using:
print(inspect.getargspec(manipulate))

# And get:
# ArgSpec(args=['df', 'factor'], varargs=None, keywords=None,
# defaults=None)
# __main__:1: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is
# deprecated, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()

# 4. But what I'm really looking for is a way to
# extract or store the function AND the variables
# used when the function is called, like this:
df2 = manipulate(df = df, factor = 20)

# So in the example using Inspect, the desired output could be:
# ArgSpec(args=['df = df', 'factor = 10'], varargs=None,
# and so on...
```

I realize that this may seem a bit peculiar, but it would actually be of great use to me to be able to do something like this. If anyone is interested, I'd be happy to explain everything in more detail, including how this would fit in in mye data science work-flow.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [bind the parameters to the function and create a new callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
import functools
func = functools.partial(manipulate, df=df, factor=20)
```

the resulting `partial` object allows argument inspection and modification using the attributes `args` and `keywords`:

```
func.keywords  # {'df': <pandas dataframe>, 'factor': 20}
```

and and can finally be called using

```
func()
```